# Convert simple JSON / XML to XML with namespaces in C# .NET

Tags: c#, .net, xml, json

What is the best way to convert json (or straightforward XML) to XML with namespaces (or with specific schema), **without** using strongly typed classes (C#)? (Using XSD, XSLT, template engine or other text based engine).

What is the most effective way (resources / performance)?

For example, to take the following object in json - string:

```
{
  'item': {
    'name': 'item #1'
    'code': 'itm-123'
    'image': {
      '@url': 'http://www.foo.com/bar.jpg'
    }
  }
}
```

And convert it to:

```
<foo:item>
    <foo:name>item #1</foo:name>
    <foo:code>itm-123</foo:code>
    <foo:image url="http://www.foo.bar"/>
</foo:item>
```

(The object can be more complex than the example above)

thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could use json.net in order to do so.
Read this other [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6760232/dont-use-javascriptserializer-to-convert-xml-file-of-unknown-schema-to-js/10331051#10331051)

It shows the other way round but should be pretty much the same.

Comment: I can't add namespaces to the XML with json.net, or decide about the XML scheme (http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/ConvertingJSONandXML.html), the conversion depends only on the json string.

Comment: You can try it using dynamic object with json.net:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10022731/reading-json-and-xml-from-rails-on-c-sharp

Comment: -1; doesn't answer the question. Json.net does not handle XML namespaces properly (i.e. at all)

Comment: I take it back - it does, but it's a devil to find out how, since it doesn't seem to be documented anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

With [Cinchoo ETL](https://www.nuget.com/ChoETL.JSON), an open source library, this conversion can be done easily as below

```
string json = @"
{
  'item': {
    'name': 'item #1',
    'code': 'itm-123',
    'image': {
      '@url': 'http://www.test.com/bar.jpg'
    }
  }
}";

StringBuilder xml = new StringBuilder();
using (var r = ChoJSONReader.LoadText(json))
{
    using (var w = new ChoXmlWriter(xml)
        .IgnoreRootName()
        .IgnoreNodeName()
        .WithDefaultXmlNamespace("foo", "http://temp.com")
        )
    {
        w.Write(r);
    }
}

Console.WriteLine(xml.ToString());
```

**Output:**

```
<foo:item xmlns:foo="http://temp">
  <foo:name>item #1</foo:name>
  <foo:code>itm-123</foo:code>
  <foo:image url="http://www.test.com/bar.jpg" />
</foo:item>
```

**Sample fiddle:** https://dotnetfiddle.net/MITsuL

Disclaimer: I'm author of this library.

Comment: What if the inner node has some other namespace? is this is a possibility in lib?

Comment: Yes, it is possible.

Comment: can you please share any documentation to add different namespaces to inner / child nodes? I am unable to find in current documentation

Comment: https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/5316145/Cinchoo-ETL-Converting-JSON-to-XML-with-Namespaces

Comment: thank you, it also worked if mentioned @xmlns:namespace in required JSON node